How can I make a SwiftUI List load struct/view data lazily?
In WWDC 2020, Apple was very explicit that Lists always load content lazily.
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10031/?time=468
However, with a very simple example, we can clearly demonstrate that the View objects within the List are all pre-instantiated, as are the body objects. The only thing that's Lazy is the actual rendering (as we can see by adding logs for onAppear vs. onDisappear.
Comparatively, if we run the same test with LazyVStack, we'll see that only the initially visible Row structs/body are instantiated.
struct ContentView: View {
  var elements: [String] = (0..<100000).map(\.description)
  
  var body: some View {
    List(elements, id: \.self) { el in
      Row(value: el)
        .id(el)
    }
  }
}

struct Row: View, Equatable {
  var value: String
  
  init(value: String) {
    print("Row.init \(value)")
    self.value = value
  }
  
  var body: some View {
    let _ = print("Row.body \(value)")
    Text(value)
  }
}

I would have expected this to behave more like the UICollectionView that backs List under the hood. Am I missing something? Is there a way to get the View instantiation to actually be lazy?
I've seen suggestions elsewhere that List isn't lazy on Mac, but this is clearly showing it isn't lazy on iOS (up to and including 18).

Perhaps that video is referring to the rendering rather than the loading? My understanding is that lists are not loaded lazily which is why LazyVGrid and LazyHgrid were created

List indeed is backed by a UICollectionView. Although it loads everything initially (which I don't know why either), it behaves like a UICollectionView after that. When you scroll around, Row.init and Row.body are called, in the same way that UICollectionView reuses its rows.

Views are just structs, i.e. values like ints, you shouldn't care about lots of those being init. Maybe your id \.self broke it since that isn't a valid keypath to a unique property.

@malhal I had the same thought - moved to an Identifiable struct and no change...

@Paulw11 the concern is LazyVGrid is lazy on load but doesn't have reuse (similar to stacks...) - looking for a truly performant solution, as we get from UICollectionView

@malhal Equatable enables the .equatable() ViewModifier, though the usage is admittedly missing!

@John apologies thought I had deleted that mistake
